# how to create object dynamically using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my project, more than 1000 bean class are their. I need set the data to those classes using setter method or constructor for creating object.

I am using `spring` to create object. using the below code. I can create an object.

```
Object obj = (Object) appContext.getBean("CustomerBean");
obj.setId(1); //showing error
```

but I can't set the value to the particular `CustomerBean` class. To set the value it asking me to change the code like this.

```
CustomerBean obj = (CustomerBean) appContext.getBean("CustomerBean");
obj.setId(1);
```

I am having more than 1000 classes and each class having 5 to 10 variables. So please suggest me a better way to set a value to all the beans dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait, how many CustomerBeans do you have? And why do you need to set the ID?

Comment: I have 1000 different beans. i need to set the value and create object for that. after that i can convert the object into XML. For setting value in 1000 different beans, i need to create object. So i planned to go with spring. It will create an object in compile time itself.

Comment: In the loop if we passed the bean name, it can provide the object then we can set the value but spring requesting for type cast to store the object. If i type casted to particular class then it is not dynamic way. I tried with interface also.

Comment: I can store the object in a interface but using that object i couldn't access the setter and getter methods of the bean classes. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: I think that your architecture is upside-down; are the customers in a database? If not, perhaps they should be? Do you need to set the properties programmatically? If you're using Spring, there's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`; otherwise, you can hack together something similar with Apache BeanUtils. Still, this design stinks to high heaven.

Answer (score 0):

All your beans may extend from parent classes with the properties to set or use reflection to assign the fields with values after you receive them from Spring:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Executor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        setValueToObject(testClass, "stringField", "someValue");
        setValueToObject(testClass, "booleanField", true);
        System.out.println(testClass.getStringField());
        System.out.println(testClass.getBooleanField());
    }

    private static void setValueToObject(TestClass testClass, String filedName,
            Object value) throws Exception {
        Class objectClass = testClass.getClass();
        Field field = objectClass.getDeclaredField(filedName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if (field.isAccessible()) {
            field.set(testClass, value);
        }
    }

    static class TestClass {
        private String stringField;
        private Boolean booleanField;

        public String getStringField() {
            return stringField;
        }

        public void setStringField(String stringField) {
            this.stringField = stringField;
        }

        public Boolean getBooleanField() {
            return booleanField;
        }

        public void setBooleanField(Boolean booleanField) {
            this.booleanField = booleanField;
        }
    }
}
```

And notice that the beans will go for `Singleton` scope unless specified explicitly. You may change the bean scope as mentioned in [this document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes).

Comment: I am having problem in creating bean dynamically. In your code, you suggest me to pass object, field name and value. but i cant create an object dynamically. so only i cant set the values to the particular variable. Could you please help with that.

Comment: When you say you can't create object dynamically, what does that mean? Any error?

Answer (score 0):

It is against OOPs concept. You cannot call/access a method/property that is not defined in the parent (here Object) class. The Object class does not have "setId()" method.

Try this (Edited})
Just Create a `Interface ValueSet { void setValueToVariables();}`  then Implement in ValueSet to All beans.  `Class CustomerBean implements ValueSet` now you can implement setValueToVariables().  Change Object Class,  that is  `ValueSet obj = (ValueSet) appContext.getBean("CustomerBean");
obj.setId(1);`

Comment: Yeah i accept that. Is their any ways to overcome this scenario.